# jquery-ui-contextmenu on left click (instead of right)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, contextmenu

Is there an easy way to set this [context menu by Martin Wendt](https://github.com/mar10/jquery-ui-contextmenu) to be triggered by left click instead of the default right click?

Answer (score 0):

Know it is late to answer but may help to others

Looked for same option but not found so solved using workaround for left click menu. 
   Create menu with **autoTrigger: false** so menu get created but not open on right click. To open this menu you can use **open()** method of plugin which you can call on **click** event of menu object. 
Hope it will help.